# Map slices of RDD/Dataframe based on column value in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
timestamp   key  value
2016-06-29   A   88
2016-06-28   A   89
2016-06-27   A   90
2016-06-29   B   78
2016-06-28   B   79
2016-06-27   B   80
2016-06-29   C   98
2016-06-27   C   99
```

The goal is to convert it to a RDD of panda.Series in an efficient way. I want as result:

```
(A, pandas.Series)
(B, pandas.Series)
(C, pandas.Series)
```

So I want to operate on a slice of the dataframe that has the same key and give as output a tuple of (key, pandas.Series) for every slice.

Things already tried/ thoughts:

1. Spark-ts seems ideal for this use, but it seems that the python version is broken.
2. Tried a window function, but it's not suitable for such cases.
3. Instead of read them in bulk, read based on key convert to panda.Series and repeat. Too slow - not viable.

Any ideas/suggestions to achieve that in a fast and efficient manner?

Comment: _fast and efficient_? - definitely no. To get `pandas.Series` you'll have to move and group data what is one way or another inefficient not matter how you approach this.

Comment: let's rephrase it then, any way do it in parallel, using spark capabilities instead of doing it iteratively?

Comment: `df.rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(makeSeries)`  where `makesSeries` extract index and converts everything to Pandas. But it won't be efficient for sure unless groups are small.

Comment: Why do you think that window functions are not suitable? (not to create series but in general)